# 'this' not referring to es6 object inside of function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have an es6 class 'Snake' in snake.js

I have an index.js

index.js instantiates a 'Snake'

index.js calls `snake.move(dir)`

I get an error `this.isProperDir is not a function`

snake.js

```
    isProperDir(dir) {
        dir = dir.toLowerCase();
        var arr = ['left', 'up', 'down', 'right'];
        return arr.includes(dir);
    }

    move(dir) {
        console.log('a2: ' + this);
        console.log('d: ' + this.isProperDir(dir));
    }
```

index.js

```
window.setInterval(snake.move, 1000);
```

This gets printed to console:

`a2: [object Window]`

`Uncaught TypeError: this.isProperDir is not a function`

I just want to call that function inside my es6 class, I figure writing `this` would refer to the function inside that class, but it seems to instead throw errors.

Comment: please add the full code that can be run, or attach a fiddle or something, it's not clear enough

Comment: Uploaded some code to jsfiddle, its not working for some reason
https://jsfiddle.net/g403e8j6/3/

Comment: You did notice the link to the duplicate…?

Comment: I didnt understand it well, I come from a Java background, where using 'this' in a class object refers to the object itself. Are you able to help me understand my issue? The jsfiddle is there. I did look at that solution though before I posted but I didnt quite understand it

Comment: In a nutshell: `this` is set at *calltime*, and depends on how you *call* the function. When calling `a.b()`, `this` inside `b` is `a`. When calling `b()`, there is no `this` inside `b` (well, it becomes `window`). `setInterval` works something like `function setInterval(fun) { fun(); }`, hence no `this` inside `fun`. Now read the duplicate again.

Comment: Ohh alright, is there any specific reason for this, any real advantages this has over the other 'Java' approach? Just wondering why this would even be a thing?

Comment: ‍♂️ Ask [Brendan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Eich)…

Comment: Wait Im still confused o.o if you have a look at my code you can maybe see why.
in my `window.setInterval(snake.move, 1000)`, would mean that inside `move()` in the snake class, `this` would refer to the `snake` variable.